# Can't pass two parameters in my URL to retrieve in my views with buttons

Tags: html, django

I am coding my first Django website (a fantasy sport website) and I am encountering a problem with the management of my requests.

Basically what I want to do is allow two request.GET.get() methods on the same html page.
Right now I have two different buttons that successfully send information through the URL that I can retrieve and filter in my views.py. The problem is that I can't get them both to work at the same time.

My main page is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Main/`

A user on my website will be able to manage multiple teams. This user will be able to navigate through their teams with the following HTML:

`<div onclick="chooseTeam()"><a href='?team_number={{team.number}}'>X</a></div>`

Which send the team number in the URL as such: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Main/?team_number=X`

This number is then recuperated in the views.py with:

`team_number = request.GET.get('team_number', 1)`

This first part works exactly as planned. The problem arise when a user who has already navigated to a specific team try to activate another button. For example, I have a filter button that allows the user to only see canadian players on the main page. This goes in the HTML as follows:

`<p><input id="CanadianPlayerFilter" type="checkbox"  name="Canadian" <label for="CanadianPlayerFilter">Canadian</label></p>`

Similarly to my team navigation button, this command passes the argument in my URL as follows:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/Main/?Canadian=On`

Now this method does not permit me to combine the two is an URL that would look like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/Main/?team_number=X/?Canadian=On`

or

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/Main/?team_number=X&?Canadian=On`

Is there a way I could make this work without creating many different paths in my urls.py to accomodate every possibility?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is handle the redirect manually. ie use window.location.href to get the current url, concatenate any additional query params and then redirect the user to that page, which should rerender the page with the correct information.

```js
const currentPath = window.location.href
const newPath = currentPath + queryParamKeyValueString
window.location.href = newPath
```